# Nspredicate match characters in array of string

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

```
NSString *str = @"A X P X P X L X E R A N D O M";
NSArray *strArray = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:@" "];

NSArray *words = @[@"APPLE", @"ORANGE", @"LEMON"];
```

I have bunch of alphabet letters in *str, what is the best way to match them against each character of words in *word array, so that @"APPLE" returns a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I do not know if this is the best way, it do not use NSPredicate, but it is a way that you can achieve what you want.

```
NSString *str1 = @"A X P X P X L X E R A N D O M";

NSCharacterSet* c = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:str1];
NSArray *words = @[@"APPLE", @"ORANGE", @"LEMON"];

for (NSString* s in words) {
    if ([[s stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:c] isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSLog(@"%@ is a match",s);
    }
}
```